# Increment DateTime value based on total number of days

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, for-loop

When a user adds a class they choose the start date and the end date of the class. I have been able to calculate the value between the end date and start date. I was able to create a For loop to insert a row into the Class table for each individual day the class is on. E.g 01/03/17 - 05/03/17 runs for 5 days so it adds in 5 total rows to the Class table.

Currently for each row it adds in the start date as 01/03/2017 00:00:00 and end date 05/03/2017 00:00:00.

For each row I want to increment the date by 1 until the end date has been reached

For example:

```
01/03/2017 00:00:00  
02/03/2017 00:00:00   
03/03/2017 00:00:00   
04/03/2017 00:00:00   
05/03/2017 00:00:00
```

[image]

Below is my code for my For loop:

```
  public class UpdateTimetable
  {
    internal void insert_days(int moduledata, int? recurrencedata, DateTime startdatedata, DateTime enddatedata, int classtypedata, int roomcodedata, int starttimedata, int endtimedata, string totalday)
    {
        int tdays = Convert.ToInt16(totalday);
        for (int i = 1; i <= tdays; i++)
        {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            myConnection.Open();

            string query = "INSERT INTO Class (ModuleId, ClassTypeId,  ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId, RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId) VALUES (@moduledata, @classtypedata, @starttimedata, @endtimedata, @roomcodedata, @startdatedata, @enddatedata,  @recurrencedata)";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            //myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@daydata", DayId);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduledata", moduledata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classtypedata", classtypedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdatedata", startdatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddatedata", enddatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomcodedata", roomcodedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttimedata", starttimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtimedata", endtimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recurrencedata", recurrencedata);

            myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code for calculating the total number of days between start and end date.

```
            int moduledata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlModule.Text);
            DateTime startdatedata = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text);
            DateTime enddatedata = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text);
            int classtypedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClassType.Text);
            int roomcodedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRoomCode.Text);
            int starttimedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartClassTime.Text);
            int endtimedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndClassTime.Text);

            startdatedata = DateTime.Parse(txtstartdate.Text).Date;
            enddatedata = DateTime.Parse(txtenddate.Text).Date;

            TimeSpan totaldays = enddatedata - startdatedata;

            // This is rounding the TimeSpan to the day value only
            string totalday = ((int)Math.Round(totaldays.TotalDays, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString();
```

[image]

```
public class UpdateTimetable
{
 internal void insert_days(int moduledata, int? recurrencedata, DateTime startdatedata, DateTime enddatedata, int classtypedata, int roomcodedata, int starttimedata, int endtimedata, string totalday)
    {
        int tdays = Convert.ToInt16(totalday);

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(tdays);
        DateTime endDate = enddatedata;

        List<string> Dates = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days; i++)
        {
            Dates.Add(startDate.AddDays(i).ToString());
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            myConnection.Open();

            string query = "INSERT INTO Class (ModuleId, ClassTypeId,  ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId, RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId) VALUES (@moduledata, @classtypedata, @starttimedata, @endtimedata, @roomcodedata, @startdatedata, @enddatedata,  @recurrencedata)";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            //myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@daydata", DayId);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduledata", moduledata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classtypedata", classtypedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdatedata", startdatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddatedata", enddatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomcodedata", roomcodedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttimedata", starttimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtimedata", endtimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recurrencedata", recurrencedata);

            myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

}

[image]

Comment: What's your specific question/problem?  Are you looking for `DateTime.AddDays`?

Comment: I have added an image of how I want the new rows to be saved incrementing by each day within the end date

Comment: Too many images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loops, you can generate the values like so:

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QDQKX23942

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170301'
declare @thrudate date = '20170307'

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(datetime,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto      /* 100 days */
      cross join n as kilo     /* 2.73 years */
      --cross join n as [tenK]    /* 27.3 years */
   order by [Date]
)

select StartTime=dateadd(hour,9,d.date), EndTime=dateadd(hour,10,d.date)
from dates d
```

returns:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|      StartTime      |       EndTime       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 01.03.2017 09:00:00 | 01.03.2017 10:00:00 |
| 02.03.2017 09:00:00 | 02.03.2017 10:00:00 |
| 03.03.2017 09:00:00 | 03.03.2017 10:00:00 |
| 04.03.2017 09:00:00 | 04.03.2017 10:00:00 |
| 05.03.2017 09:00:00 | 05.03.2017 10:00:00 |
| 06.03.2017 09:00:00 | 06.03.2017 10:00:00 |
| 07.03.2017 09:00:00 | 07.03.2017 10:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Or better yet, use a Calendar table:

Calendar and Numbers table references:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

---

To combine this with your existing insert statement, you could use a query like so, no loop needed.

```
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @startdatedata,@enddatedata)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(datetime,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @startdatedata))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto 
      cross join n as kilo  
   order by [Date]
)

insert into Class (ModuleId , ClassTypeId , ClassScheduleStartTimeId 
  , ClassScheduleEndTimeId , RoomCodeId , StartTime , EndTime , RecurrenceId ) 
select 
   @moduledata
 , @classtypedata
 , @starttimedata
 , @endtimedata
 , @roomcodedata
 , StartTime= d.Date + s.StartTime
 , EndTime  = d.Date + e.EndTime
 , @recurrencedata
from dates d
  cross apply (
    select StartTime = convert(datetime,ClassTime)
    from ClassSchedule 
    where ClassScheduleId = @starttimedata
    ) as s
  cross apply (
    select EndTime = convert(datetime,ClassTime)
    from ClassSchedule 
    where ClassScheduleId = @endtimedata
    ) as e
```

In this example the `@starttimedata` and `@endtimedata` would be integers that represent the hour. If you need add by the minute, you can switch to `dateadd(minute...`.

There are other ways to add time to a date, but it depends on what types your parameters are and what values you are sending.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for suggesting that but I'm not familiar with using your method. I do need a for loop to add the data to the database as it pulls through all the values that the user has selected on the front end.

Comment: @dcraven added an example to illustrate how you can do both at once.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this. Much appreciated ! I know have learnt a new method to do this :)

Comment: I tried to make this work in my code but I can not get it to work. Do I include the whole code you provided in a query string?

Comment: @dcraven Yes, What are the values you are sending for int `startimedata`
and  `int endtimedata`. e.g. are the hours or minutes from midnight?

Comment: Please see last image attached. starttimedata and endtimedata are Foreign Keys to the ClassSchedule table which I have attached in the screenshot. So my goal is so when the user selects a start and end time e.g 9:00am - 10:00am this represents 2 & 3. I then want to add the time values to the startdatedata which is a DateTime . Does that make sense? So if they select a start date as 01/03/2017 it will add the start time 09:00:00 to the startdatadata as 01/03/2017 09:00:00.

Comment: @dcraven Okay, so `@starttimedata` and `@endtimedata` are `ClassScheduleId`s ? and `ClassTime` is a `datetime` datatype or a `time` datatype?

Comment: Yes starttimedata and endtimedata are ClassScheduleIds and the classtime is a datetime datatype.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137165/discussion-between-sqlzim-and-dcraven).

Comment: Hi Im sorry to bother you again, Ive been trying to work out how to detect clashes. So before the clicks enter and inserts the data, I want to see if the room they selected is already used for that day between any time? It just checks to see if any of the times over lap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591064/for-loop-not-working-as-expected-with-incrementing-value

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to get a new date object from a given one plus `n` days you can do

```
DateTime dt = someOldDt.AddDays(n);
```

Comment: I have added an image of how I want the new rows to be incremented by each day up to the end date. I basically want to change the start date for each new row inserted within the for loop. The corresponding end date will have the same date as the start date.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I think i found what you want. Look at below code please:

```
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5); //5 days ago.
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

        List<string> Dates = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days; i++)
        {
            Dates.Add(startDate.AddDays(i).ToString()); //sample!
            //if enddatedata is the date that must icrease and startDate is the first Date:
            enddatedata = startDate.AddDays(i);

            // SQL insert HERE
        }

        //Dates:
        //2017-02-26 5:45:25 PM
        //2017-02-27 5:45:25 PM
        //2017-02-28 5:45:25 PM
        //2017-03-01 5:45:25 PM
        //2017-03-02 5:45:25 PM
        //2017-03-03 5:45:25 PM
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But I want to increment each new row for each day. Would you have to do 24 hours in that case?

Comment: How do you add one day in reference to my code? I have them one hour apart because that is what the user selected on the front end. I added in my code for calculating the total day value ^

Comment: To add one day to start date: `DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);` It manage the last day of month, If it has 28 days or 30 days or 31 days.

Comment: Ok thanks I tried that but I have attached the above error message I get when I change TimeSpan totaldays  to int

Comment: NO... totalDays is an int. it is enough: `totalDay = totalDays.ToString();` If you want change it to string. There is no need to this any more: `((int)Math.Round(totaldays.TotalDays, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))`

Comment: Thanks but this did not work correctly. I chose two dates which have 5 days apart and it inserted 12 rows. The dates did not increment :( I attached the code that I am running in my for loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137159/discussion-between-dcraven-and-farzin-kanzi).

Comment: Of course the dates do not Increment!! Because you did not affect them by `startDate.AddDays(i)` This code that I write `Dates.Add(startDate.AddDays(i).ToString());` is a sample for you to see the proccess and use it to make your own dates. What is the date that you want Increase? `enddatedata` ?